# Is this code valid?

Tags: c, c99

For compatibility reasons, I want to define an iterator macro that works like this:

```
elem_type *ptr;
ITERATE(&container, ptr) {
    // This will loop through every element of the container
    // ptr will point to the current element.
}
```

I have an iterator type that must be initialized with a function call, and works like this:

```
iter_type iter;
iter_init(&container, &iter);
while((ptr = iter_next(&iter))) {
    // ...
}
```

So, this is the solution I came up to squeeze this sequence into the macro:

```
#define ITERATE(container_ptr,elem_ptr) \
    for(iter_type _iter = ( \
        iter_init(container_ptr, &_iter), _iter); \
        (elem_ptr = iter_next(&_iterator));)
```

So, as you can see, there is a little trick with the comma operator, in order to fit both a variable declaration and the function call initialization in the first colon of the `for`. Is this code valid C99, and will always work?

Comment: valid? define valid. does it compile might be a first step. Also, you're not the first one to invent this macro, its a common thing - Check the linux kernel

Comment: My definition of valid is given in: "and will always work". If that is not clear enough, by "always" I meant every C99 complaint implementation. And it is irrelevant that I am not the first to invent this macro, if I didn't knew where to look for it. Lastly, how can it be in kernel code if the C99 switch is not enabled in the build options?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "portable"

Comment: @DanielMargosian Not if I explicitly named an ISO standard. In that case, the word is really valid.

Comment: "Does my code adhere to the C99 standard?"

Comment: C99 is not C standard! It is outdated and has been withdrawn when C11 was released.

Comment: @Olaf Ah, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's valid and will always work.

Just taking your for loop,

```
    for(iter_type _iter = (iter_init(container_ptr, &_iter), _iter); \
        (elem_ptr = iter_next(&_iterator));)
```

and specifically the *initialization clause* `iter_type _iter = (iter_init(container_ptr, &_iter), _iter)`, you can see that the comma operator is involved here.

The *comma operator* always evaluated left to right and there's a sequence between each of its operands.

Comment: Actually, the comma-operator is a binary operator, so it only has two operands. And I think you mean _sequence **point**_?